# Encoding polyline from List LatLng flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

noob question. I'm new to dart/flutter but working on an app where I have to convert a `List<LatLng>` coordinates to a nested `List<List<num>>`. So that it can be encoded into a polyline using another helper function.

This is my error:

```
Error: The argument type 'List<LatLng>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<List<num>>'.
```

This is where my `List<LatLng>` is being created from a `List<PointLatLng>`.

```
final List<PointLatLng> result =
                        await polylineGetter.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
                      apiKEY,
                      _curLoc.latitude,
                      _curLoc.longitude,
                      geolocation.coordinates.latitude,
                      geolocation.coordinates.longitude,
                    );
final List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

                    for (var point in result) {
                      polylineCoordinates
                          .add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
                    }
```

How can I convert this to a generic nested List to feed into this helper function from a different library? Below is an example of where I need to convert it with hardcoded values.

```
final coords = encodePolyline([[38.5, -120.2],[40.7, -120.95],[43.252, -126.453],]);
```

This is the function I need to use

```
encodePolyline(List<List<num>> coordinates, {int accuracyExponent = 5}) //encodes a list of coordinates into an encoded polyline stirng
```

Tried a few things with no luck but not exactly sure what to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume coordinates is the List

```
List<List<int>> result = coordinates.map( (data) => [ data.latitude , data.longitude ] ) ;
```